# How do I attach eventListeners to dynamically generated radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, radio-button, addeventlistener, dynamically-generated

I want to attach an event listener to each radio input click, so that I can retrieve that radio input's value and assign it as the value of a new property in the current question object in the allQuestions array.

**I'm not sure why I'm having difficulty making `choice.addEventListener` work.**

My HTML:

```
<div id="quiz"></div>
<button id="button">Next</button>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var allQuestions = [{question: "What is the capital of the Czech Republic?", 
                choices: ["Skopje", "Budapest", "Prague", "Bucharest"], 
                correctAnswer: 2},

                {question: "When was the Declaration of Independence signed?",
                choices: ["1492", "1776", "1812", "1791"],
                correctAnswer: 1}];

var quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
var index = -1;

var next = function() {
    index += 1;
    quiz.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[index]['choices'].length; i++) {
        var choice = document.createElement('input');
        choice.type = 'radio';
        choice.name = 'choices';
        choice.value = i;
        choice.addEventListener('click', function() {
            alert('hi');
        });

        quiz.appendChild(choice);
        quiz.innerHTML += allQuestions[index]['choices'][i] + '<br>';
    }
};

var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', next);
```

Comment: did you try to add the eventhandler to choice before append it?

Comment: @rmjoia, yes, but it still doesn't work if I place `choice.addEventListener` after `quiz.appendChild(choice);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use markup and DOM elements at the same time. Here's the main problem:

```
quiz.appendChild(choice);
quiz.innerHTML += allQuestions[index]['choices'][i] + '<br>';
```

The first line appends a DOM element with an attached event handler to the `quiz` element. The second line converts the contents of `quiz` to an HTML string, appends some further text (markup) to that string, and then parses that HTML and **replaces** the content of `quiz` with the parsed result. That wipes out anything not represented in the HTML, including the dynamically-added event handler.

The solution is not to do `innerHTML += ...`, which is almost always a bad idea. In this particular case, you can do this:

```
quiz.appendChild(choice);
quiz.appendChild(document.createTextNode(allQuestions[index]['choices'][i]));
quiz.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

...which also has the advantage that any characters that are special in HTML (like `<`) are treated literally (because that's what `createTextNode` does).

---

Now, having said that, you don't need handlers on every radio button. Instead, you can use *event delegation* by using a handler on your `quiz` element, and then using `e.target` within the handler to know which radio button was clicked:

```
quiz.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT") {
        var value = e.target.value; // The value of the clicked radio button
    }
});
```

That way, you don't have to worry about adding handlers dynamically; just do it once, after the `quiz` element is known to exist, and you can update its content all you want without having to worry about attaching handlers to the radio buttons within.

To do event delegation in general, you usually have to loop starting from `e.target` and going to its `parentNode` in order to find the element you're interested in (say you're interested in a `div`, but the click was on a `span` inside it); but of course, `input` elements can't have any elements inside them, so it's simple here.

You're probably wondering why the check on the tag name. If you associate your radio buttons with `label` elements (as is usually good practice), either by putting the `input` *inside* the `label` or using the `for` attribute on the `label`, you'll see *two* clicks when you click the `label`: One on the label itself, and a second one on the `input` that the label relates to. We're only interested in the one on the actual radio button.

Here's a simple example of the delegation above:

```js
var quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
quiz.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT") {
        var value = e.target.value; // The value of the clicked radio button
        console.log("The value of that radio button is " + value);
    }
});
for (var n = 0; n < 5; ++n) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<label><input type="radio" value="' + n + '" name="answer"> Radio ' + n + '</label>';
    quiz.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="quiz"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful!